# How do I set the font size in an iPhone text field?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField in a view (on an iPhone) but the input text appears very small. I don't see an option in Interface Builder to set the size.

Is there a way to set it declaratively or do I have to resort to code?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The key mistake that I was making was expecting it to be in the regular inspector - it's not, it's accessed from the Fonts dialog.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it in code as well:

```
 myUITextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Press Cmd-T for the Fonts panel.